# Identity server 4: get access toke on asp.net webform .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using Identity serve4 for user authentication and authorization and one of my clients is asp.net webform written on .NET 4.5. When the user tried to access the protected webform I am redirecting the user to identity server for authentication. But after authentication, there is a logic which based on currently logged userid, and for getting the current user login info I have to call some token endpoint which requires the token? I inspected the webform after login and I noticed there are some auth cookies. Now my question is how do I get token from this? On asp.net core we get an access token using the httpcontext below method but how do we get the same on asp.net webform using .NET 4.5?

```
var access_token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to save the access token in the cookie after authentication. Change the code on client to be like this:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                Scope = "openid profile api1",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                }
            });
```

And then you can retrieve the access_token from current user's claims, like this:

```
var accessToken = user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;
```

I explained it with details here: https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/#call-an-authorized-api-endpoint-using-access-token

Edit:

To set Identity.Name add this code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ...
                TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                }, // This is to set Identity.Name                 
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for response. Actually I was  trying to call the /connect/userinfo endpoint from asp.net webform (.NET 4.5 )  using the UserInfoClient. But looks like this is not supported on .NET 4.5. Do you have sample code demo which is using HttpClient instead of UserInfoClient  to get the userinfo details? Thanks

Comment: /connect/userinfo is just a get endpoint which requirer bearer on authorization header: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html#userinfo-endpoint - to call it you can use sth like this ```var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo");```

Comment: Actually, I was trying to follow this https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient/Startup.cs and here userinfo result returns the claims and adding that return claim to claim. I am trying to mimic the same behavior with HttpClient.

Comment: Use the code I posted with `n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken` for access token - response would be like ```{
    "sub": "248289761001",
    "name": "Bob Smith",
    "given_name": "Bob",
    "family_name": "Smith",
    "role": [
        "user",
        "admin"
    ]
}``` you can deserialize it to any object and use it

Comment: @LilRazi any luck?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the logged userid using "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" and I am not able able. I am getting null. Not sure what went wrong

Comment: Add this ```TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                }``` on UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication to set the Identity.name - checkout my post https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/ its mvc but gives you better view of whats going on @LilRazi

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had to implment IProfileService interface to get username. After implementing it I was able to see the username on the JWT token.

Comment: @lilrazi thats ok just its too much just to get the username, I would try what I suggested instead but ur call. Ill update our convo result to the answer in-benefit of others seeing this question